# Иноязычные названия, оканчивающиеся на согласный

Tags: грамотная-речь, заимствования, окончания

Как будет правильно: кубок города Салехард или города Салехарда?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **кубок города Салехарда.**

Это известный город, употребляется и без родового названия, вписывается в систему склонения существительных в русском языке. **Здесь важно не то, что город иностранный, а то, что название склоняется в русском языке и хорошо известно.**

Розенталь [§197. Приложения – географические названия](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_07)

**Названия городов**, сел, деревень, поселков, усадеб, выраженные склоняемым существительным, как правило, **согласуются в падеже** с определяемым словом, например: в городе Москве, у города Смоленска, над городом Саратовом; в деревню Дюевку,  в селе Ильинском.

Названия озер, заливов, проливов, каналов и т.д. не согласуются, но возможные варианты согласования относятся **к немногим хорошо знакомым названиям**, которые часто употребляются самостоятельно, без родового наименования, например: мимо острова Цусимы; северная половина острова Сахалина; на острове Сицилии; в пустыне Сахаре.

**Названия местечек, аулов, кишлаков, застав** не согласуются с родовым наименованием, например: в местечке Ельск, недалеко от аула Арысыпай, в кишлаке Гилян. **Не согласуются названия станций и портов**, например: на станции Орел, у станции Боярка; регулярные рейсы между портами Одесса и Александрия; из польского порта Гдыня, из аэропорта Борисполь.

Comment: Не согласен с тем, что название города известно - так можно сказать о любом городе. Грамота ру приводит такой пример Названия, оканчивающиеся на согласный
Иноязычные названия, оканчивающиеся на согласный, обычно не склоняются в функции приложения: в городе Луисвилл, в городе Мобеж, в г. Ниамет, в провинции Зядинь, близ города Мэнстон. (Исключение составляют названия, давно заимствованные и освоенные русским языком: в городе Вашингтоне.)
Если же подобные названия не употреблены в функции приложения, они, как правило, склоняются: в городе Мантасас, но в 70 километрах от Мантасаса

Comment: Хорошо известно - это и значит освоено. Когда мы говорим  "в Салехарде" - всем понятно, что речь идет о городе. А вот о Луисвилле  не все могут сказать - что это, гора, залив или город.  Так что неправильно в ответе?  Все признаки указаны: склоняемость, освоенность, узнаваемость без родового названия. Что вы еще добавите? Кроме того, освоенность - вещь относительная и зависит от аудитории, не которую текст рассчитан, например:Отель-музей Louisville 21c расположен в нескольких минутах ходьбы от Музея Слаггер в городе Луисвилле.  Вот уже и это название "освоено".

Comment: *в г. Ниамет* === Позор Грамоте... Правильно *Ниамей.*